# I'm lost with this python program

Tags: python, list

```
import sys
import pathlib
import os
def GetAndSplitCommand(line, file):
    if line is 1:
        line = 0
    f=open(file)
    lines=f.readlines()
    unsplit=lines[line]
    split=unsplit.split()
    return split

def ExecuteCode(*args):
    lists = [item for item in args]
    print(lists)
    parameters = args
    if lists[0] == "hi":
        HelloWorld()
        return
    elif lists[0] == "bye":
        GoodbyeWorld()
        return

def HelloWorld():
    print(" Hello World!")
    return
def GoodbyeWorld():
    print(" Bye World!")
    return
command = GetAndSplitCommand(1, "food.txt")
ExecuteCode(command)
```

In food.txt I have the word "hi", so, with this code it should print out "Hello World!", however it simply prints out [['hi']]. I have tried many times to reformat the code and I need advice as to what I need to do.

Also, its not a indentation issue, stackoverflow just isn't nice with my code.

Another note, this program is essentially meant to read the line of a file, split the line into separate "parameters", and using the ExecuteCode() function, do something ifthe first parameter is X.

Comment: Are you executing the script with some arg ? If you don't, it won't enter in 'hi' or 'bye'

Comment: For starters, you can remove the first three lines from `ExecuteCode` and replace `lists` with `args`, to the same effect. Also, are you aware that the first line in a file is line #0, not #1?

Comment: Learn logging and how to [debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)... these are crucial skills every developer needs.

Comment: It prints `[['hi']]` because you have `print(lists)`. The `if` block is not getting executed.

Comment: One more thing: `line is 1` must be `line==1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you've misunderstood what `*args` does in a function declaration.

When you write `def ExecuteCode(*args):`, you're staying that you want to allow `ExecuteCode` to be called with a variable number of arguments. For instance, other code could call `ExecuteCode("foo", "bar", "baz")` (three arguments) or `ExecuteCode()` (zero arguments). The `args` variable in the function will be a list of those argument values (so `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` or `[]` for my two example calls).

In your code, you're calling the function with one argument `ExecuteCode(command)`. If `command` is the list `['hi']`, then inside `ExecuteCode`, `args` will be `[['hi']]`, since it always puts the arguments in a list, since there might be several of them.

You probably don't need to use `*args` here. Instead, just use:

```
def ExecuteCode(lists):
    if lists[0] == "hi":
        ...
```

Note that there are a few other style issues with your code (that won't prevent it from running, but do make it more complicated or confusing that it needs to be). One issue is naming. A common Python convention is to use `lowercase_names_with_underscores` for most functions, and reserve `CapitalizedNames` for classes. Another issue is picking names that are clear about what they do. The `lists` variable in `ExecuteCode` is an example of this. In your current buggy code it's a list of lists, so that name *might* make some sense (if that was what you wanted), but if you change it as I suggest above to be a list of strings, you should rename it something else, since it's no longer a list of lists.